# FloatingActionButton z-index change delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, z-index, material-ui

I have a problem where a div that's supposed to always be below a FloatingActionButton (FAB) is temporarily above it when changing z-index values. When clicking the FAB, an invisible overlay is added at z-index 1000, then the div and the FAB are set to 1001 and 1002, respectively, to be clickable over the overlay.

But when changing their z-index values, the FAB seems to have a delay when it is applied, causing a visual artifact of the hidden portion of the div to be visible for ~½ second or so.

I believe it to be linked to the animation/transition of the FAB, but even with `disableTouchRipple` and `disableFocusRipple` the problem remains.

Here is an MCVE:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {FloatingActionButton, MuiThemeProvider} from 'material-ui';

const styles = {
  s1: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 32,
    top: 32,
    left: 10,
    background: 'black'
  }, s2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 80,
    top: 20
  }, overlay: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 1000
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  }

  render() {
    let menuStyle = {
      ...styles.s1,
      zIndex: this.state.open ? 1001 : 10
    };

    let fabStyle = {
      ...styles.s2,
      zIndex: this.state.open ? 1002 : 20
    };

    return (
     <MuiThemeProvider>
      {this.state.open && <div style={styles.overlay}/>}
      {this.state.open && <div style={menuStyle}/>}
      <FloatingActionButton style={fabStyle} onClick={this.onClick}>{'\u2728'}</FloatingActionButton>
     </MuiThemeProvider>
    );    
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can see it running here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k97m0yryw5

I made a workaround with a timeout and a `delay` state member, only changing the menu's z-index after about 400ms. But since this menu has buttons on it with tooltips, it is weird if you are quick with your mouse.

Comment: Can you do something like this - declare the styles in the constructor, then change them in the onclick with the state: https://codesandbox.io/s/n7wrvx0r8j (not sure if this is how you do react)

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, so the `open` member may not have changed by the time the style updates you added run against the state. That's why the style updates are in the render function, which is called after any state updates are complete. But, the problem is not really with my code -- it's with the FAB, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a `transition: 450ms` in the FAB component, and suspected that is the cause of your problem.

Just forcing `transition: 0` was enough for solving, but I can't guarantee if any animation will cease working.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {FloatingActionButton, MuiThemeProvider} from 'material-ui';

const styles = {
  s1: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 32,
    top: 32,
    left: 10,
    background: 'black'
  }, s2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 80,
    top: 20
  }, overlay: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 1000
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  }

  render() {
    let menuStyle = {
      ...styles.s1,
      zIndex: this.state.open ? 1001 : 10
    };

    let fabStyle = {
      ...styles.s2,
      zIndex: this.state.open ? 1002 : 20,
      transition: 0,
    };

    return (
     <MuiThemeProvider>
      {this.state.open && <div style={styles.overlay}/>}
      {this.state.open && <div style={menuStyle}/>}
      <FloatingActionButton style={fabStyle} onClick={this.onClick}>{'\u2728'}</FloatingActionButton>
     </MuiThemeProvider>
    );    
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/m5xwj6j9q9

Comment: At this point animations are less important than keeping the UX from being rear-ended.